# Comando Say | Enviar mensajes a un canal especifico

Tags: python, discord.py

he estado probando el comando say para poder enviar mensaje en un canal especifico dentro del servidor (say #canal texto) y me ha funcionado, pero he querido hacerlo un poco mas complejo y es que cuando no detecte un canal pueda enviar el mensaje en ese mismo canal(así como el comando basico: say texto), pero no logro conseguirlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```py
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, channel:discord.TextChannel,* , message):
    if not channel:
        channel=()
    embed=discord.Embed(
        description=(message),
        color=discord.Color.blue()
    )
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera mas facil de poder enviar a un canal especifico seria agregarlo por la id en discord, primero debes de activar el [modo desarrollador en discord](https://www.islabit.com/115086/como-habilitar-deshabilitar-modo-desarrollador-discord.html), luego de esto tienes que darle click derecho al canal y darle en [copiar id](https://noticiast.com/donde-puedo-encontrar-mi-id-de-discord-como-encontrar-su-id-de-usuario-servidor-mensaje/)

Luego de tener estas opciones arregla el código

```
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx,id_chat,* , message):
    channel = id_chat
    embed=discord.Embed(
        description=(message),
        color=discord.Color.blue()
    )
    try
        
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await channel.send(message)

    except:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send("Canal no encontrado")
```